# Problem to integrate admob interstitial with Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, publish, interstitial

I have a source code without **Interstitial**. I  am trying to add it but it shows error `Cannot resolve method showAdInter()`

Here is the fragment

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    boolean exitApp = false;

    private void launchInter()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4164100745099699/5685474562");
        //set the adListener
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdListener() {
                showAdInter();
            }
            @Override
                public void  onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            }
            @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                if (exitApp)
                    finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited Grammar. Fixed formattting

Answer (score 0):

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-2404474835802386~9054675954");

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ca-app-pub-2404474835802386/3008142357);
```

add this method for load advertisement :

```
    public void startGame() {
    // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button,    and kick off the timer.
    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

so now you just call this method when display ads.

```
   public void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        System.out.println("add is not loaded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now not working. You now need to declare in a new method and the "isLoad" keyword is now outdated